# How to load a loader on all actions in master page in asp.net using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, loader

I am using belowcode for loader but it is working on page load only but I want loader in every action in website using masterpage.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function e() {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#pageloader').fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); })
        })

    })

</script>
```

please help me.

Comment: Okay, but what is the problem?

Comment: On all ajax'ed actions? Because for full postbacks this should work fine.

Comment: my problem is loader is shown only on page load while postback it takes time to show loader but i want to show loader in every action like clicking buttons or master page tabs etc and terminate it automatically while content is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using webforms and asynchronous callbacks you could do this (very well documented on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx) by the way).

javascript:

```
var app = Sys.Application;
app.add_init(ApplicationInit);

function ApplicationInit(sender) {
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
  {
      prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
      prm.add_endRequest(endRequest);
  }
}


function beginRequest(sender, args){
    $('#pageloader').fadeIn('slow') //or whatever you do to show the pageloader
}

function endRequest(sender, args){
    $('#pageloader').fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); })
}
```